# Textbox change event - Java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box names FYMONTH1END , the value to FYMONTH1END text box is coming from java script calender. I have to call CalculateMS2() js function when any date assigned to
the FYMONTH1END column or existing date is changed. I tried onchange,oninput events but its not working. Can anyone help me out.

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="FYMONTH1" id="FYMONTH1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="FYMONTH1START" id="FYMONTH1START" size="6" readonly ><a href="javascript:NewCal('FYMONTH1START','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
<td><input type="text" name="FYMONTH1END" id="FYMONTH1END" size="6"size="6"  readonly onchange="CalculateMS2();" onblur="CalculateMS2();" oninput="CalculateMS2();">
<a href="javascript:NewCal('FYMONTH1END','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
</tr>


<script>
function CalculateMS2()
{
var month1end=document.getElementById('FYMONTH1END').value;
alert(month1end);
}
</script>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="FYMONTH1END" id="FYMONTH1END" size="6" readonly onchange="CalculateMS2();" >

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: ... and the name of the used calendar library.

Comment: have you tried oninput="CalculateMS2()" ? and please post your code? and why readonly?

Comment: @Mark Ng posted the code. value is coming to FYMONTH1END from calender pop up page(cannot post that js code here, its so big), hence its read only.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will only work if you will include jquery library.

```
jQuery('#FYMONTH1END').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the textbox value programmatically, it does not Fire any of the event like onchange,oninput etc so will have to trigger the event explicitly while textbox value is being changed, for example

```
document.getElementById("FYMONTH1END").value ='';
document.getElementById("FYMONTH1END").onchange();
```

OR through JQuery something like

```
$("#FYMONTH1END").val("").trigger("change");
enter code here
```

Hope this helps you.